# Getting Different Intensity Values in MATLAB and Java Program output

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am working in digital image processing field, i have set of mammogram images in **.bmp** format, when i am opening anyone image using **MATLAB** then i am getting intensity value as **0** for a particular location (i,j), but when i am opening this image from **java program** using **BufferedImage** then i am getting intensity value as **59** for same location (i,j). Please tell what is reason behind it.

Comment: Maybe because Java uses 0-based indexing while matlab uses 1-based indexing? Anyway, I doubt this question is suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilities -

Color image, in which case you have three indices in MATLAB, e.g. `I(i,j,k)` where k is 1, 2 or 3

0-based vs 1-based indexing. First pixel is I(1,1) in MATLAB, I(0,0) in Java

MATLAB indexes by row then column, BufferedImage's getRGB function does column (x) then row (y)

I suggest starting at (1,1) and getting them to match. Then try (1,2) and (2,1).